# Windows Phone | Refresh,Home And Stop Buttons C# 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, browser, refresh

Please someone help me to fix this issue.

I just don't know how to do it because of the new 2012 version!

How could I make an Refresh, Home and an Stop button/action
for my webBrowser (Windows Phone 8) which will be released really soon.

Comment: post your code here which you did for previous versions and let us know what error you are receiving in 2012

Comment: How can you release your own Web Browser without having even such elementary operations finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Refresh

   ```
   browser.Navigate(url);
   ```
2. Stop

   ```
   private void browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventargs e)
   {
        if(isCancelNavigation) 
        { 
            e.Cancel = true; 
            isCancelNavigation = false;
        }
   }
   ```
3. Home

   ```
   browser.Navigate(homeLink);
   ```

For Refresh and Home, using 'Navigate' is the only option I know, as there are no built in operations provided by browser control. Please suggest me, if there's a better way to do it.

For Stop, Have a bool and set it to true when the user clicks Stop.